# bottomnavigationview Fragment replacement with sub-fragment

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have created an app with a bottom navigation fragment which consists of 5 main fragments and one extra sub fragment (login Fragment). the thing is I want this login fragment to be replaced with the userAccount fragment once user has logged in successfully.

Note: I am running the App statically at first so I am using a variable Boolean Called Status to check whether user has logged in or not

```
private static final boolean Status = false;

final Fragment f1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment f2 = new SearchFragment();
final Fragment f3 = new CameraFragment();
final Fragment f4 = new ChatFragment();


final Fragment f5 = new AccountFragment();


// logginFragment page should be replaced with AccountFragment once user logged in successfully
final Fragment f6 = new logginFragment();

private BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {


                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f1).commit();
                        active = f1;
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f2).commit();
                        active = f2;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_camera:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f3).commit();
                        active = f3;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_chat:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f4).commit();
                        active = f4;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_account:

                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f5).commit();
                        active = f5;
                        return true;
                }
          /* \getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    selectedFragment).commit();*/


                return false;

            }
        };
```

Comment: why no one help to solve this question? this is really weird is it so hard ?!!!!

Comment: I would separate auth `Fragments` in another `Activity` or first `Activity` and keep this rest `Fragments` in this `Activity` so after login is successful start second `Activity` if user is already login immediately start second `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Your Code changes the fragment only when one of the Bottom Navigation Bar item is selected. You can replace the login fragment with account fragment when the login is successful(i.e when button is tapped) and set it to active rather than listening for the change in selection. Let me know if this helps.

```
void login()
{
   if(Successful)
    {
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.fragment_login,R.id.fragment_account)
                                .commit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sir, I think you didn't get my question clearly, I have created 5 xml fragments with their java classes so once each one called by its class it will be created within its assigned tab ( inside the bottom navigation view), I just want the fifth tab to consist of an extra added loginFragment on top of UserAccount fragment so once user authenticated successfully UserAccount fragment will replace on top of loginFragment

Comment: just to let u know that I have put all of fragment under a single frameLayout                               fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f5, "5").hide(f5).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f4, "4").hide(f4).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f3, "3").hide(f3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f2, "2").hide(f2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f1, "1").commit();

Comment: I think you can do the same.. but do it in the loginFragment class and then, set the case rlated to nav of account to loginFragment. Once the login is done , replace with AccountFragment. You can also do this by  checking the Status. if Status is true, replace fragmentContainer to AccountFragment else with Login Fragment

Comment: i have done same as you said but the problem is that it will replace the whole container so all tabs will become userAccount. while i am only targeting single tab

Comment: here is the container in which I have included all the fragments                                           <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       />