# How to pass data from an activity to a fragment inside a navigation drawer android

Tags: java, android

A navigation drawer with 3 Fragments, the third Fragment has a TextView with an on Click listener. Once it has been clicked a layout activity will open on the top which includes a ListView to allow the user to select/click on a specific Item, so later on this selected item info should be displayed on that TextView within the third fragment.

is there any method to pass data because I have used a class to pass data but the TextView wouldn't be refreshed with the sent data

**This works as a design pattern to share arguments between the Activity and third fragment**

--------------------------DataHolder Class---------------------------------

```
 public class DataHolder {

 private static DataHolder dataHolder = null;

private DataHolder() {
   }

  public static DataHolder getInstance() {
 if (dataHolder == null)
     {dataHolder = new DataHolder(); }


 return dataHolder;
 }


 private  String item;

  public String getItem() {
return item;
  }

 public void setItem(String item) {
  this.item = item;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Does your `TextView` click listener starts new `Activity` with `ListView` in it or?

Comment: yes sir exactly as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find using `startActivityForResult` not sufficient in your case or using `EventBus`, you can overcome this by using `SharedPreferences` and `Fragment/Activity` lifecycle.

So once you start new `Activity` first `Activity` will go in `onPause` and with it all its `Fragments` will be put in `onPause`. When user clicks on one of the `ListView` items in your second `Activity` you can store the value inside `SharedPreferences` like:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SecondActivity.this)
            .edit().putString(key, selectedItemInfoHere).apply();
```

Then `override` inside your first `Activity` and in your third `Fragment` method `onResume()` and inside just make checking:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String value = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext())
            .getString(key, "");
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
        //You have selected item value update TextView
    }
}
```

Note that once you don't need this value you will need to remove it, because it will update your `TextView` every time when `onResume` is called. To remove value just call:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit().remove(key);
```

Comment: bro in the method onResume  this .getString(key, "what should be here")

Comment: An empty string “”, default value that is why in if statement you check that is not null and not empty so basically like I wrote in code

Comment: You are the best bro that works smoothly. Thank you so much

Comment: bro u have answered my question here and thank you for that. I also wish that u would answer my another question if u can because it seems no one has answered it . here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245531/bottomnavigationview-fragment-replacement-with-sub-fragment

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have flow 3rd fragment --> activity which should update fragment which launched it. In this case, as for me, the most clean solution is from your opened activity call  `startActivityForResult` method to call activity-host of your fragments and handle all what you need in overridden `onActivityResult` method. Than just call your fragment's `updateTextView()` or something like that.

On the other hand you can use [this library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to send messages between components, but you should be careful with usage and think about corner cases related to components lifecycle.

So, choose solution according your needs:)

Comment: startActivityForResult i have used it, but I for my case it is not sufficient because i need to call the main Activity which encapsulate all the fragments

Comment: is there any method apart from this library ?